# Katalon Studio: WebUI.verifyElementText not seeing the text in an element

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am trying to write a test case in Katalon Studio that will attempt to verify the contents of various fields against expected values. I am using the `WebUI.verifyElementText()` function to do this. I know that the element is being found (I verified in the Katalon debugger), but it fails the test indicating that the expected and actual values do not match. Below is the typical call I'm making:

```
WebUI.verifyElementText(findTestObject('SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name'), 'Task Allocation')
```

When the test case is run, it fails with an error like the following:

```
Test Cases/SC_Import/Verify_Import FAILED because (of) Verify element text of test object 'Object Repository/SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name' FAILED. (Root cause: Actual text '' and expected text 'Task Allocation' of test object 'Object Repository/SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name' are NOT matched.)
```

I don't understand why this is failing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says

```
Test Cases/SC_Import/Verify_Import FAILED because (of) Verify element text of test object 'Object Repository/SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name' FAILED. (Root cause: Actual text '' and expected text 'Task Allocation' of test object 'Object Repository/SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name' are NOT matched.)
```

that the actual text of the test object is `''`.

So, try using `WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name'), 'value')` and then comparing it to wanted text:

```
def testText = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('SC_Elements/InitServiceInfo/service_name'), 'value')

WebUI.verifyMatch(testText, 'Task Allocation', false)
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Found that you could also use `WebUI.verifyElementAttributeValue`. This essentially combines the get attribute call with the verify match call in one.

Answer (score 1):

Could you paste the html and screenshot of the element. Sometimes the text visible in Web is not actual text, it can be stored in 'value' attribute. In this case, you have to get the attribute value and make the comparison on this value.